# Symbols keyboard UITExtField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

How do I set up a UITextField to show the symbols keyboard (the one with + - /  on the first line ) . It doesn't seem to be in the drop-down ... I don't really need the numeric one, but I need the math symbols +/- etc.

Comment: you can create your custom keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom keyboard `textfeild.inputView=customKeyboard;`

[Input Views and Input Accessory Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW2)

[link](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/)

This is my custom keyboard :[image: My Custom Keyboard]

I used iCalculator.h & iCalculator.m classes from this [Source](http://newtechsid.wordpress.com/apple/appledevlink/xcode-tutorial/developing-the-icalculator-application/)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
_calculator=[[iCalculator alloc]init];}
```

This is my -(IBAction) method

```
-(IBAction) press:(id) sender{  
 [_calculator input:[sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
 [textfield setText:[_calculator displayValue]];
}
```